# c++ member variable type overriding in inheritance class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I am now looking for a way to override the "Member Variable Type" in C ++ inheritance.

For Example:

```
class MemberBase
{
    protected:
       char* data;
    public:
       void print_data( void ) { printf("%s\n", data); }
};

class MemberDerivedA : public MemberBase
{
    protected:
       int number;
    public:
       void print_A_data( void ) { printf( "A: %d\n", number); }
};

class MemberDerivedB : public MemberBase
{
    protected:
       double real;
    public:
       void print_B_data( void ) { printf( "B: %lf\n", real); }
};
```

and

```
class Base
{
    protected:
       MemberBase* a;
    public:
       Base( MemberBase* a ) { this->a = a; }
       void use( void ) { a->print_data(); }
};

class DerivedA
{
    public:
         DerivedA( MemberDerivedA* a ) : Base(a) { this->a = a; }

         // I want to use the "a" member variables as "MemberDerivedA" types 
         void use_A( void ) { a->print_A_data(); }

};
```

In the above code, I would like to use the MemberDrivedA class's print_A_data function in the DrivedA class through a member variable a, which inherits from the Base class.
(Of course, the object pointed to by a "pointer a" in DerivedA class is actually an object of type MemberDrivedA)

Of course I can do this with pointer type casting.( cast "a" MemberBase* type to MemberDrivedA* type in DrivedA ) However, I want to find more easy way than casting all access of a.

Is there any way to override "member variable type"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   // I want to use the "a" member variables as "MemberDerivedA" types
> ```

You choices:

1. Store a pointer to the `MemberDerivedA` object in `DerivedA` in addition to what the base class stores.
2. Perform a `dynamic_cast` of the pointer being held by the base class. Use the pointer only if the cast succeeds.
3. Rethink your code so you don't need either of the above. This, IMO, is the best choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried 1 but gave up because sometimes I access member variable "a" in Base class.  The second solution is good solution. But as I said earlier, I want to know if there is another way. Thanks.

Comment: @WON, I can't think of a fourth choice.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely positively no way to have covariant variables without cheating the type system.

```
class Base
{
    protected:
       virtual MemberBase* a; // imaginary syntax
    public:
       Base( MemberBase* a ) { this->a = a; }
   void use( void ) { a = new MemberDerivedA; } // oops we just broke MemberDerivedB
};
```

One way to deal with the situation is to use a covariant virtual *function* instead.

```
class Base
{
    protected:
       virtual MemberBase* a() = 0;
    public:
       Base( ) = default;
    // whatever
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you made the `print_data` function virtual in `base` class and override it in the `derived class`?

```
class MemberBase
{
    protected:
       char* data;
    public:
       virtual void print_data( void ) { printf("%s\n", data); }
};

class MemberDerivedA : public MemberBase
{
    protected:
       int number;
    public:
       void print_data( void ) { printf( "A: %d\n", number); }
};

class MemberDerivedB : public MemberBase
{
    protected:
       double real;
    public:
       void print_data( void ) { printf( "B: %lf\n", real); }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, sometimes i should call print_data() in Base class while print_data() and print_A_data() are called in DerivedA class.